# MongoDB aggregation: remove some elements from embedded array (redact?)

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, mongodb-3.6

I'm querying a MongoDB collection to extract informations, thus only aggregation operations are possible (i.e. no `update()`).

From several documents shaped like these, where each contains an embedded array with at least one document with a `partNum : "1200664"` field):

```js
{
    "recType" : "H1",
    "progCount" : "097314238",
    "items" : [ 
        {
            "qty" : "00011",
            "partNum" : "4471719"
        },
        {
            "qty" : "00027",
            "partNum" : "1200664"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "recType" : "H1",
    "progCount" : "175564685",
    "items" : [ 
        {
            "qty" : "00027",
            "partNum" : "1200664"
        }
    ]
}
```

I'm trying to get the following result, where each document maintains its shape (so no `$unwind` or `$replaceRoot` stages are allowed), but all the embedded array elements that would not satisfy a `{$match: {partNum: "1200664"}}` are removed:

```js
{
    "recType" : "H1",
    "progCount" : "097314238",
    "items" : [ 
        {
            "qty" : "00027",
            "partNum" : "1200664"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "recType" : "H1",
    "progCount" : "175564685",
    "items" : [ 
        {
            "qty" : "00027",
            "partNum" : "1200664"
        }
    ]
}
```

I did several attemps with the `$redact` pipeline stage, but I can't come up with a working invocation, let alone obtain any result similar to the above.
I'm even wondering whether `$redact` is the correct operation here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might need to use `$filter` in `$project` stage to filter array elements. `$eq` used in the `cond` to filter all non matching array elements

```
{
    $project : {
        items : { $filter : { input : "$items", as : "item", cond : { $eq : ["$$item.partNum" , "1200664"] } } }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm getting a `Unexpected token :` error

Comment: I made some edits, mistakenly put a  `:` instead of `,` and changed `$ne` to `$eq` can you try this one?